# How to fix table creation error in android sdk?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to create table with multiple column.But I am facing some issues.Here is the my code :

```
    package com.edkul.vimal.edkul;

    import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.ContentValues;

    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "studentRecord.db";
        private static final String TABLE_STUDENT = "StudentRecords";
        private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
        private static final String COLUMN_STUDENTNAME = "StudentName";
        private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "StudentEmail";
        private static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "StudentPassword";
        private static final String COLUMN_CPASSWORD = "StudentConfirmPassword";
        private static final String COLUMN_INSTITUTE = "InstituteName";
        private static final String COLUMN_CONTACTNO = "ContactInfo";

        public DatabaseHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public DatabaseHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
            super(context, name, factory, version, errorHandler);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STUDENT + " ( " +
                    COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
                    COLUMN_STUDENTNAME + " TEXT " +
                    COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT " +
                    COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT " +
                    COLUMN_CPASSWORD + " TEXT " +
                    COLUMN_INSTITUTE + " TEXT " +
                    COLUMN_CONTACTNO + " TEXT " +
                    " ) ";
            db.execSQL(query);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_STUDENT);
            onCreate(db);
        }

        //add new row to the database
        public void addStudent(StudentRecord studentRecord){
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_STUDENTNAME,studentRecord.get_Name());
            values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL,studentRecord.get_Email());
            values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,studentRecord.get_Password());
            values.put(COLUMN_CPASSWORD,studentRecord.get_Cpassword());
            values.put(COLUMN_INSTITUTE,studentRecord.get_Institute());
            values.put(COLUMN_CONTACTNO,studentRecord.get_Contact());
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            db.insert(TABLE_STUDENT, null, values);
            db.close();
        }

        //Delete the student record from the table

        public void deleteStudent(String studentName){
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_STUDENT + "WHERE" + COLUMN_STUDENTNAME + "=\" "+ studentName + "\";");
        }

        // print the database as a string

        public String databaseToString(){
            String dbString = "";
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_STUDENT + "WHERE 1" ;
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
                if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("studentName")) != null){
                    dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("studentName"));
                    dbString += "\n";
                }
            }
            db.close();
            return dbString;
        }
    }
```

```
com.edkul.vimal.edkul E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "Records": syntax error
com.edkul.vimal.edkul E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.edkul.vimal.edkul, PID: 1992 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Records": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Student Records(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT Student Name TEXT Student Email TEXT Student Password TEXT Student Confirm Password TEXT Institute Name TEXT Contact Info TEXT )
```

I am trying to create table with 6 column.But I am not able to insert entry into database due to above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Table Name** and **Table Column Name** should not contain a *Space*. So, either remove the space or replace it with an underscore (`_`).

If you want to keep the *Space*, wrap the names in double quotes (`"`). For example:

```
create table "abc xyz" ("first name" string);
```

**EDIT:**
Your `query` string should be somewhat like this:

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STUDENT + " ( " +
                    COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    COLUMN_STUDENTNAME + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_CPASSWORD + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_INSTITUTE + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_CONTACTNO + " TEXT" +
                    ")";
```

Comment: Thanks,I followed the instruction but now i am getting following error                                    
near "StudentName": syntax error
03-02 22:35:51.176 15700-15700/com.edkul.vimal.edkul E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.edkul.vimal.edkul, PID: 15700
                                                                       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "StudentName": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE StudentRecords(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT StudentName

Comment: There should be a *space* between `StudentRecords` and `(`. Also, the column names should be separated by a comma (`,`).

Comment: how and where to put comma . i am very new to this dont have any idea.I have edited my code and inserted space but can you please suggest me .

Comment: Happy to help ... :)